# Visualizing the Anchor Point of a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

Is there an easy way of putting a mark (like a cross for example) on the anchor point of an UIImageView? I'm trying to line up several rotating images by their anchor point, and being able to see these points would make the job a lot easier.

Many thanks.

Comment: Add a subview and set the position as the anchor points * the size?

Comment: Or align them using the position of the underlying layers?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean in an answer?

Comment: BTW - your article on "the Math behind Transforms" is an excellent read - very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking how to visualize the anchor point within a view but it seem to me that you are asking for it so that you can help align the anchor points. I'll try and answer both questions.

## Visualizing the anchor point.

Every view on iOS have an underlying layer that has an anchor point. The anchor point is in unit coordinate space of the layer (x and y goes from 0 to 1). This means that you can multiply x by the width and y by the height to get the position of the anchor point inside the layer in the coordinate space of the view/layer. You can then place a subview/sublayer there to show the location of the anchor point.

In code you could do something like this to display a small black dot where the anchor point is.

```
CALayer *anchorPointLayer = [CALayer layer];
anchorPointLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
anchorPointLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 6, 6);
anchorPointLayer.cornerRadius = 3;

CGPoint anchor = viewWithVisibleAnchorPoint.layer.anchorPoint;
CGSize  size   = viewWithVisibleAnchorPoint.layer.bounds.size;

anchorPointLayer.position = CGPointMake(anchor.x * size.width,
                                        anchor.y * size.height);
[viewWithVisibleAnchorPoint.layer addSublayer:anchorPointLayer];
```

You can see the result in the image below for four different rotations.

[image: View rotated around anchor point]

## Aligning layers by their anchor point

That is cool and all but it's actually easier then that to align anchor points.

The key trick is that the `position` and the `anchorPoint` is *always* the same point, only in two different coordinate spaces. The position is specified in the coordinate space of the super layer. The anchor point is specified in the unit coordinate space of the layer.

The nice thing about this is that views that have their `position` property aligned will automatically have their `anchorPoint` aligned. Note that the content is drawn relative to the anchor point. Below is an example of a bunch of views that all have the same y component of their `position`, thus they are aligned in y.

There really isn't any special code to do this. Just make sure that the `position` properties are aligned.

[image: Multiple views aligned by their anchor point.]